# Trying to read a .txt file and store it into a private arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, bufferedreader

I am trying to read a file and store it into a private class arraylist however I am getting this compiler error: WordList.java:8: unreported exception java.io.IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class WordList
{
  private ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
  public void main(String[] args)
  {
    ArrayListConstructor("Cities.txt");
    System.out.println(words);
  }
  public void ArrayListConstructor(String filename) throws IOException
  {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
    String line = br.readLine();
    while (line != null)
    {
      this.words.add(line);
      line = br.readLine();
    }
    br.close();
  }
}
```

any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: don't capitalize method names

Answer (score 0):

Add `throws IOException` to  the `main`

```
public void main(String[] args) throws IOException
```

or wrap the method in a `try/catch` block

```
public void main(String[] args)
{
    try{
       ArrayListConstructor("Cities.txt");
    }
    catch(IOException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(words);

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package testing;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class WordList
{
    private static ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        arrayListConstructor("Cities.txt");
        System.out.println(words);
    }
    public static void arrayListConstructor(String filename) throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
        String line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null)
        {
            words.add(line);
            line = br.readLine();
        }
        br.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are throwing a IOException exception in method ArrayListConstructor(String filename) So whenever you use this method you should catch this exception

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class WordList {

private ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

public void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ArrayListConstructor("Cities.txt");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception occured");
    }
    System.out.println(words);
}

public void ArrayListConstructor(String filename) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
    String line = br.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        this.words.add(line);
        line = br.readLine();
    }
    br.close();
 }
}
```

OR you can throw this exception again

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class WordList {

private ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

public void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ArrayListConstructor("Cities.txt");
    System.out.println(words);
}

public void ArrayListConstructor(String filename) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = null;
    br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
    String line = br.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        this.words.add(line);
        line = br.readLine();
    }
    br.close();
 }
}
```

Comment: What does throwing and catching do? I have never understood the purpose of catching, but when I used throwing it seemed to tell the system that there will be an error, but ignore it. @sambaheerathan